# Linux IP bridge and vlan_filtering

Tags: networking, network-interface, ip, routing, vlan

I'm using DSA in Linux to support an ethernet switch (KSZ9897). The switch is behaving but I'm having trouble setting up the bridge vlan filtering features through Linux (kernel 4.19).

I create the bridge and add the member ports like this:

```
ip link add name br0 type bridge
ip link set dev lanB master br0
ip link set dev lanA master br0
```

At this point, Linux creates the br0 interface and I can ping through this interface to a PC connected to the 'lanB' interface.

Now I want to separate lanA and lanB using VLANs. 
Enable vlan filtering, and set up PVIDs:

```
ip link set dev br0 type bridge vlan_filtering 1
bridge vlan add dev lanB vid 2 pvid untagged master
bridge vlan add dev lanA vid 3 pvid untagged master
```

With VLANs setup, I can dump bridge vlan state:

```
bridge vlan show
port     vlan ids
lanB     2 PVID Egress Untagged

lanA     3 PVID Egress Untagged

br0      1 PVID Egress Untagged
```

Here we come to the problem. Now I need to set the br0 interface as 2 PVID so that I can ping between the CPU and LANB. But I receive an error:

```
bridge vlan add dev br0 vid 2 pvid
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

If I can't change the pvid of the CPU port I'm not sure how to accomplish this. My end goal was to use `ip link add link br0 name br0.2 type vlan id 2` to add a vlan interface in order to communicate with lanB. But without configuring the br0 switch port to be part of VLAN 2 this will fail.

Am I approaching this wrong or missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the command for altering the bridge vlans needs slightly different syntax. 'self' must be appended to the device:

```
bridge vlan add dev br0 self vid 2 pvid
```

Then the command works as expected.